# How to modify/update google calendar event with onEdit trigger?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

So I have been experimenting on google form - calendar- sheet using google app script. I was able to automatically add event to google calendar from form submission. But I am still struggling with modifying the event directly when user edited their response.

So first endtime from new submission will be turned into object and then checked if there will be conflict with another submission from other users:

```
function getEndTime(request){
  request.endTime = new Date(request.dateout.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
}


function getConflicts(request){
  var conflicts = request.calendar.getEvents(request.date, request.endTime);
  if (conflicts.length > 0) {
    request.status = "Conflict";
  } else {
    request.status = "Approve";
  }
}
```

If there is no conflict, the calendar will be updated

```
function updateCalendar(request){
  var event = request.calendar.createEvent(
    "Booked",
    request.date,
    request.endTime
    )
}
```

This is the onFormSubmit function (with form submission trigger):

```
function main(){
  var request = new Submission(lastRow);
  getEndTime(request);
  getConflicts(request);
  draftEmail(request);
  if (request.status == "Approve") updateCalendar(request);
  sendEmail(request);
}
```

This is the onEdit function (with onEdit trigger) along with change() function:

```
function Change() {
  this.statusArray = sheet.getRange(1, lastColumn, lastRow, 1).getValues();
  this.statusArray = [].concat.apply([], this.statusArray);
  this.index = this.statusArray.indexOf('');
  if (this.index == -1) return;
  this.dateArray = sheet.getRange(1, lastColumn - 4, lastRow, 1).getValues();
  this.dateArray = [].concat.apply([], this.dateArray);
  this.dateoutArray = sheet.getRange(1, lastColumn - 3, lastRow, 1).getValues();
  this.dateoutArray = [].concat.apply([], this.dateoutArray);
}

function onEdit() {
  var change = new Change();
  while (change.index != -1) {
    change.status = change.statusArray[change.index];
    change.row = change.index + 1;
    var request = new Request(change.row);
    if (change.status == 'Sent: Conflict') {
      change.statusArray[change.index] = 'Conflict';
      request.status = 'Conflict';
      sendEmail(request);
      sheet.getRange(change.row, lastColumn).setValue('Sent: Conflict');
    } else {
      getEndTime(request);
      change.statusArray[change.index] = 'Approve';
      updateCalendar(request);
      sendEmail(request);
      sheet.getRange(request.row, lastColumn).setValue('Sent: Approve');
      break;
        }
    }
    change.index = change.statusArray.indexOf('');
  }
```

Even with this set of code, the edit submission will always have conflict with the previous own submission. (for example, if I first submit to book from May 17 to May 19, then I edit it to May 17 to May 21, my edited submission will have conflict with the previous own submission). How can I delete the previous event, and then replace it with new own submission on edit? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) or [update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) methods to change the existing event.

If you want to completely remove it then you should the use [delete](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete) method.

Comment: thank you! much appreciated! I will try it